# Drupal: rogrammatically change file system path

Tags: drupal, file

Is there a way to change the files directory path, using a function from the drupal api?

Thanks in advance,

—Albe

Answer (score 4, accepted):

EDIT: Failed initial reading comprehension. Answer:

```
variable_set('file_directory_path', 'path/to/files');
```

Drupal uses `conf_path() . '/files'` as the default fallback value.

#### Answers to Related Questions

To change the location of the files directory itself, check out the File System configuration page at admin/settings/file-system. You can change the path of the files directory to any Drupal-writable path on your server.

If you mean, how do you change the path to which files are saved within the files directory, that depends on what you are using to do file uploads.

- *Upload module:* The Uploadpath module mentioned by @vilepickle looks good.
- *[Filefield](http://drupal.org/project/filefield) module*: It already allows the path to be configured by global and user tokens in a similar way to uploadpath, and configurable by the node information where you upload the file by [Filefield Paths](http://drupal.org/project/filefield_paths).
- If you are using IMCE or one of the assortment of graphical file managing modules, this is answered on a per module basis.

Comment: There's also a 'site_directory_path', to change where Drupal looks for new themes?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about this exactly, but the module http://drupal.org/project/uploadpath lets you specify a different upload directory per node type.